# Failed to connect Azure servicebus topic using JMS - Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-servicebus-topics, jms-topic

I followed steps as mentioned in [Azure ServiceBus JMS Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/spring-jms-service-bus/tree/master/spring-jms-service-bus-topic-sample) with below properties

```
spring.jms.servicebus.connection-string=Endpoint=sb://test-dt.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=key
spring.jms.servicebus.topic-client-id=12345
spring.jms.servicebus.idle-timeout=18000
spring.jms.servicebus.pricing-tier=Standard
```

however I get below error

```
ERROR 43904 --- [ntContainer#0-1] org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection        : Failed to connect to remote at: amqps://test-dt.servicebus.windows.net:-1
ERROR 43904 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'test-topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=6, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: handshake timed out after 10000ms
```

On the other hand, I followed steps as mentioned in [ServiceBus without JMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) and added transportType as AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS then I am able to connect.

We want to implement using spring boot starter and listener method, instead of calling from (public static void main) method.

Please guide on what am I missing when following first link

Comment: From your network, AMQP port (TCP 5671 ) may have been blocked, hence the connection to the Az SB is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR 43904 --- [ntContainer#0-1] org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection        : Failed to connect to remote at: amqps://test-dt.servicebus.windows.net:-1

To resolve above error, try as suggested by [Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran):

Check if port `5671` is blocked:

```
telnet <yournamespacename>.servicebus.windows.net 5671
```

**Note:** Clients that use AMQP connections over TCP require ports `5671` and `5672` to be opened in the firewall. Along with these ports, it might be necessary to open additional ports if the [`EnableLinkRedirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.amqp.amqptransportsettings.enablelinkredirect) feature is enabled.

You can refer to [Troubleshooting guide for Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-troubleshooting-guide), [AMQP outbound port requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide) and [Port 5671 Blocked :(. What are other options?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/2554)